# ZF2 - Call to a member function on a non-object error

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to implement a simple roll-a-dice service and use it in a `.phtml` file. I know my issue has been reported often on SO, but I could not find a solution in other questions.

I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getDiceResult()
>         on a non-object in rolladice.phtml on line 11

Here is line 11:

```
<?php
    $result =  $this->rollADiceService->getDiceResult();
    echo "<p>Roll-a-dice result: ".$result."</p>";
?>
```

The controller is set-up as following:

```
class RollADiceController extends AbstractActionController
{

    private $rollADiceService;

    public function setPluginManager(PluginManager $plugins) {
        parent::setPluginManager($plugins);
        $this->rollADiceService = $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('RollADiceService');
    }
    ...
```

In `Module.php`, I have:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories'=>array(
            'LoginLogoutService' => function() {
                return new LoginLogoutService();
            },
            'RollADiceService' => function() {
                return new RollADiceService();
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

I am using the same technique (i.e., `setPluginManager`) to retrieve instances of my services in other controllers without issues. What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.:** Using a debugger, I can see that `setPluginManager()` is called, but that the `$this->rollADiceService` variable is initialized with `null`. Why?

Comment: Typically, it is the controller instance if I am right.

Comment: PHP is complaining about `$this`. You need to know what `$this` is. PHP is saying `$this` isn't an object.

Comment: I was wrong, it is an instance of PhpRenderer...

Comment: How should 'rollADiceService' be assigned to the view? That seems to be where the problem lies, but it's not obvious how that should happen from the code in your question. I've also never seen overriding `setPluginManager()` in order to set dependencies - this seems like an unintuitive approach.

Comment: It should not be assigned to the view agreed. I have refactored my code to pass the dice result as a parameter for the view. But, my service is still null.

Comment: @Tim Does it mean I should create my controller with a factory?

Comment: Do you have any references to `RollADiceService` in your `module.config.php`? And is the factory definition in `Module.php` exactly as in your question?

Comment: No and yes to your questions.

Comment: Does it work if you just grab the service and assign to the view like normal in a controller action: `$this->view->rollADiceService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('RollADiceService');`

Comment: I refactored my code to not call the service from the view. I used parameters instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, there were two issues:

i) I refactored my code to pass the result of the call to `rollADiceService->getDiceResult()` as a variable which `$this` can access.

ii) Hijacking `setPluginManager()` is not a recommended practice. I've implemented factories for my controllers depending on services.

Answer (score -1):

your problem is realy simple I think.

```
<?php
$result =  $this->rollADiceService()->getDiceResult();
echo "<p>Roll-a-dice result: ".$result."</p>";
?>
```

Add these brackets after rollADiceService should fix your problem. Without brackets, Zend View instance try to access to view variable named rollADiceService, which is obviously NULL.
By adding brackets, you tell to View it should look for rollADiceService in registered view helpers.

I hope it helps :)

Comment: It still does not find the instance.

Comment: There is nothing in the question to indicate that 'rollADiceService' should be a view helper.

Comment: Sorry, I missed AbstractActionController base class (when I saw the code, autmaticaly suppose it is view helper).